# Python binary search-like function to find first number in sorted list greater than a specific value

Tags: python, binary-search

I'm trying to write a function in Python that finds the first number in a sorted list greater than a specific value that I pass in as an argument.  I've found examples online that use simple list comprehensions to achieve this, but for my purposes I need to be performing this operation frequently and on large lists, so a search that runs in linear time is too expensive.

I've had a crack at writing an iterative binary search-like function to achieve this, though I'm coming across some edge cases where it doesn't work correctly.  By the way, the function is not required to deal with a case where there is no larger item in the list.  Here is my existing function:

```
def findFirstLarger(num, sortedList):
    low = 0; 
    high = len(sortedList) - 1

    mid = -1
    while True:
        print("low: " + str(low) + "\t high: " + str(high))
        if (low > high):
            print("Ah geez, low is " + str(low) + " and high is " + str(high))
            return # debugging, don't want this to happen
        if low == high:
            return sortedList[low]
        else:
            mid = (low + high) / 2;
            if num == sortedList[mid]:
                return sortedList[mid]
            elif num > sortedList[mid]:
                low = mid + 1
            else:
                high = mid - 1
```

One case I have noted where this function does not work is as follows:

```
>>> somenumbers=[n*2 for n in range(131072)]
>>> somenumbers[-5:]
[262134, 262136, 262138, 262140, 262142]


>>> binsearch.findFirstLarger(262139,somenumbers)
low: 0   high: 131071
low: 65536   high: 131071
low: 98304   high: 131071
low: 114688  high: 131071
low: 122880  high: 131071
low: 126976  high: 131071
low: 129024  high: 131071
low: 130048  high: 131071
low: 130560  high: 131071
low: 130816  high: 131071
low: 130944  high: 131071
low: 131008  high: 131071
low: 131040  high: 131071
low: 131056  high: 131071
low: 131064  high: 131071
low: 131068  high: 131071
low: 131070  high: 131071
low: 131070  high: 131069
Ah geez, low is 131070 and high is 131069
```

Here the correct result would be `262140`, as this is the first number in the list greater than `262139`.

Can anyone recommend a cleaner implementation of this that actually works? I didn't think this would be such an esoteric problem, though I haven't been able to find a solution anywhere as of yet.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have you tried the [`bisect` module](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html)?

```
def find_ge(a, key):
    '''Find smallest item greater-than or equal to key.
    Raise ValueError if no such item exists.
    If multiple keys are equal, return the leftmost.

    '''
    i = bisect_left(a, key)
    if i == len(a):
        raise ValueError('No item found with key at or above: %r' % (key,))
    return a[i]

find_ge(somenumbers, 262139)
```

---

Your code is wrong that (1) `low > high` is a valid termination case. (2) you should not stop at `low == high`, e.g. it will return an incorrect index when `num == 3` for your `somenumbers`.

Comment: you're correct, i had accidently put "numbers" in my post rather than "sortedList".  I've fixed that up, and also now included a concrete example of where it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: bisect looks like a winner too.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the implementation without bisect function, you can try the following code:

```
def findFirstLargerOrEqual(num, sortedList):
    '''Finds the smallest index in the sortedList
    of the element which is greater-than or equal to num'''

    slen = len(sortedList)
    start = 0

    while slen > 0:
        m = start + slen//2

        if sortedList[m] < num:
            slen = slen - (m+1 - start)
            start = m+1
            continue

        if start < m and sortedList[m-1] >= num:
            slen = m - start
            continue

        return somenumbers[m]

    raise ValueError('Not found')

somenumbers=[n*2 for n in range(131072)]
print(findFirstLargerOrEqual(262139, somenumbers)) #output: 262140
```

Comment: This doesn't compile, due to somenumbers being undefined.