# (JS) clean way to find smallest number greater than X in Set()

Tags: javascript

I have a set of numbers and an init number.

```
const mySet = new Set([1, 4, 5])
const initVal = 2
```

I want to find the smallest number greater than the initVal in mySet.

I could do something like...

```
let myArray = Array.from(mySet)
let smallestNumSoFar = Infinity
for (let num of myArray) {
    if (num > initVal && num < smallestNumSoFar) smallestNumSoFar = num; 
    }
```

But I was looking at [this answer for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101592/algorithm-python-find-the-smallest-number-greater-than-k) and it looks soo clean. Can anyone think of a nice one liner for javascript to do this? Something like `Math.min of numbers>X in mySet`

Comment: Do you need to do it efficiently, e.g. repeatedly on a large set? There are data structures that can implement a `Set` with *fast* O(log n) lookup of the smallest element greater than some value, not just short. (Alternatively, if your set never changes, you can get the same effect with a binary search.)

Comment: "nice one liner" is not neededt. If you're going to reuse this (and thus need less code for every time you try) just write a function and call it.

Comment: Efficiency isn't so important, the set is <1000 numbers. And yes it's a function now, and I agree one-liners aren't important from a practical standpoint. But at the same time... I still appreciate a good one-liner. !needed !== !cool ;)

Comment: [Off-topic]: Minor corrections to JS in your question: 1. `new Set` is a function, so it uses `()` not `{}`. 2. In JS, you should always declare your variables (mostly with `const`, or `let` if you explicitly ressign it) and 3. You want to use `for(_ of _)` not `for(_ in _)`. They're quite different and the `of` one is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the same efficiency of the Python example linked (`O(n)`), here's a simple one-liner.

```js
const mySet = new Set([1, 4, 5]);
const initVal = 2

const min = Math.min(...[...mySet].filter((val) => val > initVal));

console.log(min);
```

You first need to convert the `Set` to an `Array`, then `.filter` it, and then use that with `Math.min`. `Math.min` expects multiple arguments, so the spread operator (`...`) is needed there. Similarly, to convert the `Set` to an `Array` (since `Set`s don't have a `.filter` method), it must be spread so that it's not an array with the 0th element being the set itself.