# Is the binary search algorithm used in core python?

Tags: python

I'm looking for instances in the core python 2.x that uses the binary search algorithm. Do you have any quick pointers where to look ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556496/python-binary-search-like-function-to-find-first-number-in-sorted-list-greater-t

Comment: take a look at the bisect module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bisect module uses a binary search.  Here's a link to the source code:  http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/bisect.py

Most of the rest of the Python core uses either hash tables or linear searches.