# Are there any tips to make my Python code faster for Hackerrank?

Tags: python, performance, coding-efficiency

I'm trying to solve a coding problem for Hackerrank but continuously run into timeout errors for my code taking too long to run. I know that it works perfectly fine, indentation is not the problem, there is nothing 'wrong' with the code at all. I just need tips on how I can make it run more efficiently:

```
def main(n, o, q, m): 
    for x in m:
        for y,z in enumerate(o):
            x -= z
            if x<=0:
                print y+1
                break
        if x>0: print -1
```

> o and m are a list of integers that are looped through subtracting the values of o from m until m is less than 0, the loop finishes and m is still not less than 0 it will print -1. The ultimate goal is to find which int from o finishes m.

Comment: You could pre-compute the partial sums of `o`.

Comment: fix the indent for `if x> 0 : ....` and what exactly will you be trying to `break` out of the loop for, do you want to execute both if statements if not remove `break` and the print statements need `()` around them

Comment: @PeterWood I can't pre-compute because I need to obtain the index at which the amount was finished.

Comment: @FishingCode Ive update the question, I would break out of the loop once I find the value that finishes m, the ```ifx>0: ...``` is if the value for m is not finished after the loop it will print -1

Comment: Can the question be reopened? I think I've made it more focused.

Comment: ok, what is the correlation between x,y,z and m, if m is still not lesser than 0, than print -1 so remove the `if x>0:` statement...but again the correlation/details are unknown till we know more about the question

Comment: @PaulRooney Yes, I only want to come out of the inner loop so that it will go to the next m value. The hackerrank is: [link](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/uwi-comp2211-2020-potw-02/challenges/boss-business)

Comment: @FishingCode x is used to go through the values in m, and y,z are used to get the index and value of the values in o. I don't want to print -1 everytime the value for m is not less than 0, only after it's gone through the inner loop and subtracted all the values do I want it to print that it is '-1' if m is less than 0. This is the link to the problem: [link](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/uwi-comp2211-2020-potw-02/challenges/boss-business)

Comment: @Kayvia The index of the finishing partial sum is the same as the index of the finishing amount. Honestly, think about it a bit. Also, see [**`itertools.accumulate`**](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate)

Comment: Can values of `o` be negative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are performing subtractions using `o` for every loop of `m`.

To improve performance you need to either loop `m` less or loop `o` less.

One way of looping `o` less is to pre-calculate all the partial sums.

`x` is having values from `o` subtracted. Perhaps you'll only subtract one number, or two, or a thousand. Who knows? And you will do so for every loop of `m`.

For example if `x` were 10, and `o` were `[2, 4, 6, 8]`, the third term would be what finished the loop, the third term being `12`, the sum of `2`, `4`, and `6`.

Building a list of partial sums means the addition will only need to be done once.

[**`itertools.accumulate`**](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) can do this for you.

If `o` values can be positive or negative then you'll need to do a linear search as the partial sum won't be in ascending order. (Maybe there's a clever data structure you can use, but I don't know it.)

However if `o` values are all positive you could do a binary search of the partial sums.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3556527/1084416) to [Python binary search-like function to find first number in sorted list greater than a specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556496/python-binary-search-like-function-to-find-first-number-in-sorted-list-greater-t/27453748)

Comment: Thank you so much! Using accumulate and a binary search helped a lot.